# progressbar for uploading file in laravel

Tags: laravel, input, file-upload, progress-bar, csrf-token

my code is for input

```
<input id="imgages" name="imgages" type="file"  onchange="uploadFile()" />
```

and my script is :

```
function _(el) {
 return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("imgages").files[0];
  
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("imgages", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php"); 

  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0; //wil clear progress bar after successful upload
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

my problem is how can i chenge this part to use url for laravel and add csrf in this ajax part??
I mean I dont know how to add **csrf** token laravel in this script.

```
  ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem
I have to add token after formdata.append("imgages", file);

```
formdata.append("imgages", file);
formdata.append("_token", '{{ csrf_token() }}');
```

and I add a route for store in host.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [csrf token in the head](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/ec838c75ba1886d014c5465b1ecc79b2071f46c7/src/Auth/bootstrap-stubs/layouts/app.stub) of your html ...

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

... and use `formData.set('_token', document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'))` to send it with the request.